# WordPress functions.php + shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a template for WordPress. I have custom php code in functions.php.

I also use third-party plugins from other authors that use shortcode.

I need to execute a shortcode directly in functions.php using do_shortcode

In the functions.php file I have the following path:

```
$SIZE_LIMIT = file_get_contents('/home/fvaebvm/test3/wp-content/themes/test/offer/Plan-a.txt');
```

I need to do something like this but it generates an error.

```
$SIZE_LIMIT = file_get_contents('/home/fvaebd/test3/wp-content/themes/test/offer/<?php echo do_shortcode('[pms-subscription-info key="plan_name"]'); ?>.txt');
```

Is there a chance for this to work?

I need to use this shortcode as something like a variable that will print the name of the plan for the logged in user.

When wanting to print shortcode in template files, it works exactly as I need.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[pms-subscription-info key="plan_name"]'); ?>
```

I am new when it comes to php.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a syntax error. After formatting the path like this, everything works.

```
$SIZE_LIMIT = file_get_contents('/home/fvaebvm/test/wp-content/themes/test/offer/' . do_shortcode('[pms-subscription-info key="plan_name"]') . '.txt');
```